# `reload!` on terminal now retrieves NoMethodError

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-5, pry

I have `gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.3'` on my bundle.
My application.rb goes as follows:

```
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.load_defaults 5.2
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]

    config.generators.system_tests = nil

    if Rails.env.development?
      console do
        require 'pry'
        config.console = Pry
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection
      end
    end
  end
```

My `reload!` method was working just fine and suddenly it stopped.
gitStatus shows no changes. what are the possible causes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the line below seems to break `!reload` command while on pry.
!reload was working just fine on IRB.